# Finding Moroccan ancestors

Tags: birth-records, 20th-century, research-methods, family-tree, morocco

I would like to find some family members, but I don`t really know if they exist or not.

I only have our last name and my grandpa's name, who I have never met.  His name is possibly Adnane Toujjani, Toujjani being my own last name too. We don`t have any other information than this.

I`m from Morocco, Rabat specifically.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Your question as written is not a good fit for our site, in part because it is unclear what you're asking.  Looking for living relatives is not on-topic (see https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic in the [help]).  If you wanted help getting started with research in Morocco, we can answer that. You can edit your question at any time by using the edit link underneath the question.

Answer (score 2):

If your father is still living, your first priority is to talk to him now and to document his own life and your own.  See the FamilySearch Wiki article [Family History For Beginners](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/Family_History_for_Beginners) or other basic guides.  Collecting records and memorabilia held by your family (sometimes called "home sources") and interviewing living relatives is essential before you move back to the country of origin.  Since the FamilySearch Library (formerly known as the Family History Library) is in the United States, the Family Search Research Wiki often talks about research strategies for immigrants in terms of US immigration, but the same basic research methodology can be used for researching travel between any two countries.

Some resources for getting started with studying your family history in Morocco:

- [Questions tagged [morocco]](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morocco) on Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange
- FamilySearch Research Wiki: [Morocco Genealogy](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/Morocco_Genealogy)
- Cyndi's List: [Africa](https://www.cyndislist.com/africa/)
- WorldGenWeb: [Morocco](https://www.worldgenweb.net/morocco/)